# Определение Func<> непосредственно в вызове метода

Tags: c#

Есть некий метод:

```
void Foo(Func<string> callback) {}
```

Можно ли вызвать его, не определяя в классе другую функцию:

```
string Callback()
{
return Random.value.ToString();
}
```

Т.е. как-то так:

```
Foo(?? new ?? ... { return Random.value.ToString(); })
```

Comment: `Random.value`? Вы имеете ввиду `(new Random()).Next().ToString()`? Или это не нативный класс Random?

Comment: @Peter Olson, да, это из unity.

Comment: Окей, тогда понятно

Answer (score 3):

```
Foo(() => Random.value.ToString());
Foo(() => { return Random.value.ToString(); });
Foo(delegate() { return Random.value.ToString(); });
```

Comment: спасибо. Мне решарпер предложил поменять второй вариант на первый. Его и буду использовать.